# Can I customize the legend of my plot?

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend entries={Region,Signal},
]
    \addplot[
        fill=gray!20, draw=gray!20,
    ] coordinates {
        (0,20)
        (100,20)
        (100,40)
        (0,40)
    };
    \addplot[] coordinates {
        (0,100)
        (100,0)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like:

[image: figure]

I would like the picture next to the "Region" legend to be a gray zone/area instead of a line, but I have the following problems:

1. I can only draw my figure with `coordinates { ... }`.
2. I can only add text/commands in the `keys` of the `axis` and `addplot`s i.e. only within the `\begin{axis}[HERE]` and `\addplot[HERE]`. I can not add text anywhere else.

I know these are very rare conditions. Am I out of luck? Or is there any `legend_style ...` that I could add to the `\addplot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add options to the `\addplot` macros? If yes, you can add `area legend`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend entries={Region,Signal},
]
    \addplot[
        fill=gray!20, draw=gray!20, area legend
    ] coordinates {
        (0,20)
        (100,20)
        (100,40)
        (0,40)
    };
    \addplot[] coordinates {
        (0,100)
        (100,0)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]